# How to clear an angularJS array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 $scope.itemarray = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
```

this will clear the array but the ui wont be updated.

```
$scope.itemarray = [];
```

this works fine! why?

```
 $scope.itemarray.length = 0;
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or example

Comment: Do you have some sort of `ng-submit` happening before your clear event perhaps? Maybe you're adding to the array somehow then trying to clear it. Otherwise `= []` should be working fine

Comment: You may be doing something like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/9mth0knf/  (goes along with Petr Averyanov's answer)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`$scope.itemarray.length = 0;`  << this is correct. Length is read-write property.

`$scope.itemarray = [];` << this creates new empty array. If you have bindings to old itemarray, they may be lost. (Html binding like `ng-if="itemarray[0]"` wont be lost)

Comment: Being able to set the length on an array is bizarre but it is also the absolute fastest way to clear an array in JavaScript